# Display: none, loads page with sliding panel shut but does not display Google map correctly

Tags: javascript, css

Ok I have a sliding panel on my website (http://www.security-vacancies.net/index.php) when the link view map is pressed the sliding panel opens to show a Google map.

The problem i have is that the CSS map element has the following

```
 Display: none
```

With this in place when the web page loads the panel is closed and when i open the sliding panel the map doesn't show correctly and shows just a little segment.  Now i have read some other threads on this website that explained that the map doesn't show because display says none.

When i remove the display element the the map shows perfectly, but when the page loads the sliding panel is in the open position.  I have tried several different things to find a solution but i am having no luck and wondered if anybody knew how i could resolve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the map located on the site? I'm not seeing it on the home page.

Comment: sorry under the main picture, bottom right it says view Job map, if you click on that a sliding panel moves down and you will see it shows just a fragment of the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this problem many times. It loads the map in this way because you initiate it while it has "display: none;" and gmap initiates with canvas size 0:0.

There are two ways to solve it:

1) Load the map with the website (do not use "display: none;" on load) and onready() simulate the click on a trigger ("View Job Map") which hides the map. It will be visually visible that the map loads and then hides.

2) Do not initiate the map on load. Initiate your map after you click "View Job Map" for the first time. Remember to save somewhere that the map is initiated and check it afterwards to avoid initiating every time you trigger "View Job Map".

Comment: Thanks, To be honest that has lost me, I get what your saying but not sure how to implement it, also not sure if i like the idea of the map being visible during the page loading and then disappearing.  But at least now i know what to explore so thank you.

Comment: can you see this: `$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");` in your js?
replace this line to: `$("#panel").slideToggle("slow", function() { load(); });`. This is just a hint how to make it work. You'll need to write some additional code to make it user friendly :)

Answer (score 1):

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jobmap').on('click', '.slide', function(){
        $('#panel').slideToggle();
        $('#map').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});​

<style> #panel {display:none; height:600px; width:960px; background:#ccc;}#map {opacity:0; transition(all 0.4s linear); -webkit-transition(all 0.4s linear); -moz-transition(all 0.4s linear); -o-transition(all 0.4s linear);} #map.visible {opacity:1; transition(all 0.4s linear); -webkit-transition(all 0.4s linear); -moz-transition(all 0.4s linear); -o-transition(opacity 0.4s linear);}​</style>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it didn't work the panel stopped sliding

Comment: It works, just make sure that #map has a fixed width and height.

Comment: Does this code just swap out with the code that is already there? as when i did that the panel simply doesn't move.

Comment: It could be that your slide class is attached to an anchor. I set it up to use a span. You can see what I did here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cekDp/)

Comment: Thanks, That was really helpful, the issue i have now is i copied your code which worked fine in Opera but not ie 10 or google chrome.

Comment: here is a linkt to my plain page, thanks  http://www.security-vacancies.net/slidetest2.html

Comment: I'm getting theses two errors. Remove the body onload="load()" on body tag
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL slidetest2.html:13
Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined

Comment: Thanks, I still couldn't get it work, but appreciate your help and pushing me in the right direction, so i will see if i can get it working.

Comment: Ok I finally got the code to work, but it still doesn't show the map, it's just a grey block